# What sense does it make to pass a negative value to the Array constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I tried to pass a UInt to the Array constructor and got the error

> Type mismatch: inferred type is UInt but Int was expected

because Array wants an Int:

```kotlin
public constructor Array<T>(
    size: Int,
    init: (Int) -> T
)
```

Then I was wondering what sense does it make to pass negative numbers to the Array constructor?

Comment: Probably the answer lies in the "non-goals" section of the unsigned integer documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/unsigned-integer-types.html#non-goals

Comment: Also this array constructor existed way before the `UInt` type

Comment: @UnholySheep It is hard to believe that someone advocates the use of -1 to signal errors in a language, which knows exceptions, continuations and destructuring. I think the main reason is, that Java uses `int` to index arrays.

Comment: Java also returns `-1` for methods likes `lastIndexOf` (e.g.: in `ArrayList`) - exceptions are reserved for exceptional cases, looking for the index of an element in an array is not something that should be throwing exceptions